# How to represent the character 'E' as a single byte in source files?

Tags: rust

I have a method that receives a byte array and matches on the first byte to decide how to proceed. To do the match I represent the character as `b'E'`:

```
match first_byte {
      b'E' => {
      ...
```

I have a test for this particular case where I pass a byte array with 45 as the first byte:

```
let bytes = &[45, 00, 00, 00 ...]
```

The problem is that this seems to be ignored - 45 hexadecimal is not the same as `b'E'` to the compiler.

To make things even more confusing I have a case where I compare against the byte `b'R'` and using a byte array with 82 as the first element works just fine:

```
let bytes = &[82, 0, 0, 0...]
```

and

```
b'R' => {
```

What am I missing with b'E' and 45?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'R' is 82, or 0x52 in hex (note the `0x`)

'E' is 69, or 0x45 in hex - you're passing 45 as a decimal number, you should be writing either 69 or 0x45, otherwise you're writing down a different value